# Promise code stops executing after error handling for reject() and before resolve()

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

My code seems to stop working in the middle of execution.

My entire code snippet is here:

```
if (!userJobs.length) {
     Logger.warn("No messages to be sent");
     return reject();
}

Logger.info("Prepared " + userJobs.length + " message job(s).");
resolve(userPairs);
```

However, the message about prepared jobs never gets logged.  Neither does the warning, so I don't think the problem is that the Promise is rejected.

What I tried to do to see where the problem happens is add the following to my code:

```
console.log("message BEFORE the reject handling");

if (!userJobs.length) {
        Logger.warn("No messages to be sent");
        return reject();
}

console.log("message AFTER the reject handling");

Logger.info("Prepared " + userJobs.length + " message job(s).");
resolve(userPairs);
```

The "before" message gets logged but the "after" never does.  Can anyone help me identify why my code stops running? The promise doesn't appear to resolve OR reject, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: you are `return`ing. that stops the current function.

Comment: But the warning message "No messages to be sent" is never logged, so I don't understand how the return is called if the code never executes what's inside the if statement?

Comment: run with a debugger and see where things are going. perhaps `userJobs` is null or undefined.

Comment: well sounds like you need to debug some more.... What is `userJobs` at that moment in time. Does it have a length? Is it null?

Comment: Can you show us the complete code of that function? You shouldn't be doing that much logic in a `Promise` executor callback - put it in a `then` callback where exceptions are caught properly!

Comment: Everyone is right, userJobs was a relic from some older versions and was null at the time, thank you all!

Comment: And thank you @Bergi, I definitely do have too much logic in my executor, I will look into putting in a then() callback

Comment: There's an interesting gotcha related to exceptions and promises. If you do something like `new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { throw new Exception('exception'); })`, the exception will cause the promise to fail. BUT if the exception is thrown asynchronously, e.g. `new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { setTimeout(function() { throw new Exception('exception'); }, 1000); })`, the promise will not know about the exception, so will never be resolved or rejected.